# Problems with JSONArray randomize

Tags: java, json, random

I'm trying to randomize JSON array this way:

```
private static JSONArray getJSONArray(Context context) {
    JSONArray myJSONarr=new JSONArray();
    JSONArray myRandomizedJSONarr=new JSONArray();
    try
    {
        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("chineesecardsdata.json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        String resultJson = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");

        try {
            JSONObject myJSONObject=new JSONObject(resultJson);
            myJSONarr=myJSONObject.getJSONArray("data");
            Log.d("mainActLog","Array before random: "+myJSONarr.toString());
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    catch(
            IOException e) {        
    }

    try {
        ArrayList<Integer> intArr1 = new ArrayList<>(myJSONarr.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < myJSONarr.length(); i++) {
            intArr1.add(i);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(intArr1);
        for (int i = 0; i < intArr1.size(); i++) {
            myRandomizedJSONarr.put(i, myJSONarr.getJSONObject(intArr1.get(i)));
            if (i == (myJSONarr.length() - 1))
                break;
        }
        Log.d("mainActLog","Array after random: "+myRandomizedJSONarr.toString());
    }
    catch (JSONException e){}
    return myRandomizedJSONarr;
}
```

As a result of this not only JSON objects are randomizing, but also keys and values.
I mean, I had an array like this:

> [
>   {"id":"0","hieroglyph":"水","pinyin":"Shuǐ","pinyin_num":"Shui3","russian":["вода"],"hsk":"1"},
>   {"id":"1","hieroglyph":"人","pinyin":"Rén","pinyin_num":"Re2n","russian":["человек"],"hsk":"1"},
>   {"id":"2","hieroglyph":"日","pinyin":"Rì","pinyin_num":"Ri4","russian":["день"],"hsk":"1"},
>   {"id":"3","hieroglyph":"不","pinyin":"Bù","pinyin_num":"Bu4","russian":["нет"],"hsk":"1"},
>   {"id":"4","hieroglyph":"少","pinyin":"Shǎo","pinyin_num":"Sha3o","russian":["мало"],"hsk":"1"}]

And after randomize it looks like this

> [{"id":"2","hieroglyph":"日","pinyin":"Rì","pinyin_num":"Ri4","russian":["день"],"hsk":"1"},
>   {"id":"2","hieroglyph":"日","pinyin":"Rì","pinyin_num":"Ri4","russian":["день"],"hsk":"1"},
>   {"id":"4","hieroglyph":"少","pinyin":"Shǎo","pinyin_num":"Sha3o","russian":["мало"],"hsk":"1"},
>   {"id":"3","hieroglyph":"不","pinyin":"Bù","pinyin_num":"Bu4","russian":["нет"],"hsk":"1"},
>   {"id":"2","hieroglyph":"日","pinyin":"Rì","pinyin_num":"Ri4","russian":["день"],"hsk":"1"}]

Comment: You're overwriting your source array. You need to create a copy.

Comment: Have same result with a copy

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: ArrayList<Integer> intArr1 = new ArrayList<>(myJSONarr.length());
            JSONArray myRandomizedJSONarr=new JSONArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < myJSONarr.length(); i++) {
                intArr1.add(i);
            }
            Collections.shuffle(intArr1);
            for (int i = 0; i < intArr1.size(); i++) {
                myRandomizedJSONarr.put(i, myJSONarr.getJSONObject(intArr1.get(i)));
                if (i == (myJSONarr.length() - 1))
                    break;
            }

Comment: No, [edit] your question to add the code.

Comment: Btw, `if (i == (myJSONarr.length() - 1)) break;` is pointless.

Comment: question is edited

Comment: Looks like it should work now. Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: what json library do you use? as far as I can see its not `javax.json`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just shuffle the array directly?

```
List<JSONObject> myList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
for(int i = 0; i < myJSONarr; i++){    
    myList.add(myJSONarr.getJSONObject(i));
}
Collections.shuffle(myList);
```

Comment: It's not an array.

Comment: That code should still work, since it has a superinterface of Collection http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html. If not, he could convert it to a List and then shuffle that.

Comment: Doesn't work: Error:(67, 41) error: incompatible types: JSONArray cannot be converted to List<?>

Comment: Sorry. I updated the code in my answer to add a conversion to a list and then shuffled that. Want to give that a try?

Comment: Still wrong result. I've edited question with additional code, may be it can help

Comment: What result did you get?